# HP Pavillion dv6 laptop - No Windows 8 driver for ATI HD 5650

Tags: drivers, hp-pavilion, ati-mobility-radeon

I couldn't find the driver for ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 for my HP Pavillion dv6 laptop for Windows 8.

I have searched both AMD and HP for the driver but couldn't find for Windows 8.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: What did you try so far? Did the laptop ship from HP with windows 8 installed or with another OS? Did you check the HP site for drivers? Did you check the AMD site for drivers. Did you have a question? (None in the post, though it is easy to guess what you want). Etc etc.

Comment: No it was windows 7 installed. I got the driver for windows 7 though.

Comment: I searched both amd and hp for the driver but couldn't find for windows8.

Comment: You might want to add that to the post (use the edit link). Also look at similar posts (this has been asked before). Without that this question is likely to be closed due to "Insufficent effort/research before asking".

Comment: Did you run Windows compatibility tool before upgrading? Have you searched on the Microsoft Windows 8 hardware compatibility site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%208%20-%2064) for 64-bit Windows 8, or [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/mobile?os=Windows%208%20-%2032) for 32-bit Windows 8. *Make sure you download the right bitness driver version*.

1. Download the "AMD Mobility Radeon™ Driver Verification Tool" for the respective platform.
2. Run it.
3. If it tells you that your chip is compatible with the generic drivers, download the "Latest Beta Driver" (as of this writing, 13.11 Beta) for Mobility Radeon.
4. If the verification tool tells you that you have switchable graphics that are *not* compatible with the generic driver, then you are entirely dependent upon HP to decide to release a new driver for Windows 8; which they are not obligated or required to do. In fact it is highly unlikely that they would support an older laptop with this sort of backporting support when it would not carry a financial incentive for them to do so. Most likely they would rather leave you out in the cold so that you are motivated to buy a new laptop, which they hope will be an HP.